# How to use GridView V7 in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gridview, android-studio

i am trying to use Gridview v7 in Android Studio. i have added a jar file of GridLayoutV7 in android Studio project , but in Source file i cannot import the Grid

import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your build.gradle file. By default you should have a `dependencies` section with

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

Replace that with

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar')
```

And make sure your v7 file is in the `libs` directory.

Comment: there is no file build.gradle

Comment: Are you using a new project started in Android Studio or did you import one from IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download).
2. Open the **build.gradle** file for your application.
3. Add the support library feature project identifier to the **dependencies** section. For example, to include the **appcompat** project add **compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"** to the dependencies section, as shown in the following example:

   ```
    dependencies {
       ...
       compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I just agonized over this for a few hours but found something that worked.

Like everyone else says, import the support library using 
`compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.+'` in build.gradle

Rebuild the project, and then you can add the layout to your xml with this syntax:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout_pics"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:orientation="horizontal"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="2"
        app:useDefaultMargins="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="Button" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Notice here all the appearances of "app" instead of "android". I think that's the main reason people are having problems with this. I should add, there was one step during this where Android Studio asked me if I wanted to import the "app" namespace -- I think it was after the first time I typed an "app:"

Hope this saves people some headache.